# Override cookie in Squid

Tags: proxy, cache, cookies, squid

How can I set up Squid to replace a specific cookie so that all clients that connect through the proxy have the same cookie from the perspective of the remote website?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Next time you get a message that your question couldn't be submitted because it doesn't meet our quality standards, consider giving more background information about the problem you're trying to solve. This might get you a better response. (I'm just guessing you received the message because you included a Lipsum)

Comment: your right with the lipsum but i could not think of anything to add.